Show that $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]}g(x)f(nx)dx=\|f\|_{L^1[0,1]}\|g\|_{L^1[0,1]} $
Let $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x+1)=f(x)$ for all $x\ge 0$. Let $g:[0,2]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Show that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]}g(x)f(nx)dx=\int_{[0,1]}f(x)dx\int_{[0,1]}g(x)dx
$$

My idea is that we use step function to approximate $g$. So we first prove this result holds for $g=\chi_{[a,b]}$. Then this result holds for any step functions $\phi$.
Clearly,
$$
\int_{[0,1]}g(x)f(nx)dx=\int_{[0,1]}\chi_{[a,b]}f(nx)dx=\int_a^b f(nx)dx=\int_a^{[na]/n+1/n}f(nx)dx+\int_{[na]/n+1/n}^{[nb]/n}f(nx)dx+\int_{[nb]/n}^{b}f(nx)dx
$$
So
$$
\int_{[0,1]}g(x)f(nx)dx\le M/n+\int_{[na]/n+1/n}^{[nb]/n}f(nx)dx+M/n
$$
where we assume that $|f|\le M$ for $x\in [0,1]$.
We have
$$
\int_{[na]/n+1/n}^{[nb]/n}f(nx)dx=\frac{[nb]-[na]-1}{n}\int_0^1f(x)dx
$$
But I am stuck here...

You surely need more hypotheses...  When $f(x) = \sin(2\pi x)$ then isn't your limit is zero by the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma?

I feel like there’s an absolute value missing somewhere. Otherwise just take $g$ to be strictly positive and $f$ strictly negative and this can’t possibly hold.

@DavidGao Sorry, the RHS is not in L1 norm

Due to continuity, we know that $J_f := \int_0^1 |f| < \infty$ (since the continuous $|f|$ must be bounded on the compact interval $[0,1]$).
Write $$ I_n := \int_0^1 g(x)f(nx)\mathrm{d}x = \frac1n\int_0^n g(x/n) f(x)\mathrm{d}x\\ = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} \int_i^{i+1} \frac1n g(x/n) f(x) \mathrm{d}x\\ = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} \int_0^1 \frac 1n g(i/n + x/n) f(x)\mathrm{d}x,$$ where we have used the periodicity of $f$ in the final line. Now, since $g$ is continuous over the compact interval $[0,1]$, and thus is uniformly continuous over $[0,1]$, for any $\varepsilon > 0,$ there is an $n$ large enough so that for all $i \in[0: n-1]$, $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |g(i/n + x/n) - g(i/n)| < \varepsilon.$ Take $n$ to be so large. Then we know that $$ \int_0^1 |g(i/n + x/n) f(x) - g(i/n)f(x)|\mathrm{d}x \le \varepsilon J_f. $$ So, we have that for all large enough $n$, $$ \left| I_n - \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} \frac 1ng(i/n) \int_0^1 f\right| \le \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} \frac1n \cdot \varepsilon J_f = \varepsilon J_f \\ \iff -\varepsilon J_f + \left( \int_0^1 f(x)\mathrm{d}x\right)\sum_{i = 0}\frac{g(i/n)}{n} \le I_n \le \left( \int_0^1 f(x)\mathrm{d}x\right)\sum_{i = 0}\frac{g(i/n)}{n} + \varepsilon J_f.$$
But notice that due to the continuity of $g$, $\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} \frac1n g(i/n) \to \int_0^1 g(x)\mathrm{d}x$. If we define $I = \int_0^1 f(x)\mathrm{d}x \cdot \int_0^1 g(x)\mathrm{d}x,$ then this lets us conclude that for every $\varepsilon > 0,$ $$ I - \varepsilon J_f \le \liminf I_n \le \limsup I_n \le I + \varepsilon J_f. $$ Since this result holds for every $\varepsilon > 0,$ we can conclude by taking the limit as $\varepsilon \to 0$, which squeezes both  $\liminf I_n$ and $\limsup I_n$ to $ I$.

Here is a solution using Fourier transform, which may be complicated than what you have learned.
If you think about Fourier transform $\hat f(k)=\int_0^1f(x)e^{-2\pi ikx}dx$ and the same for $\hat g$, we have $f(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\hat f(k)e^{2\pi ikx}$, which means
$$f(nx)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\hat f(k)e^{2\pi inkx}\quad\Rightarrow f(n\cdot)^\wedge(j)=\begin{cases}\hat f(j/n)&n\mid j\\0&n\not\mid j\end{cases}.$$
On the other hand for $g,h:[0,1]\to\mathbb C$ also we have convolution formula $(gh)^\wedge(j)=\hat g\ast\hat h(j)=\sum_{k+l=j}\hat g(k)\hat h(l)$. Take $h=f(n\cdot)$ we get
$$\int_0^1g(x)f(nx)dx=(g\cdot f(n\cdot))^\wedge(0)=\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty \hat g(j)(f(n\cdot))^\wedge(-j)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \hat g(nk)\hat f(-k).$$
Let $n\to\infty$ the above tends to $\hat g(0)\hat f(0)=\int_0^1g\int_0^1f$.
